# Show Array of String in Picker View?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

How to show array of strings in picker view without using didSelect delegate method ?

Comment: Could you elaborate what *exactly* you want to achieve? It is not clear enough to let the viewers help you. You probably tried something before asking, don't hesitate to provide it in the question.

Comment: Do you have some code to show?

Comment: Please show what you have tried, as u asked **without using didSelect delegate** it is not used for showing data in PickerView.

Comment: didSelect method has nothing to do with displaying data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return 1 // the amount of "columns" in the picker view
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    return yourArray.count // the amount of elements (row)
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    return yourArray[row] // the actual string to display for the row "row"
}
```

Simple as that. No didSelect needed. The didSelect delegate function is called whenever you change your selection in the picker view. You don't need that one for displaying data